# How to test Passport OAuth 2.0 authentication with Rest Assured?

Tags: java, node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js, rest-assured

I am trying to test a REST API which is protected by OAuth 2.0 authetication from Rest Assured, so far without success.

The environment is structured so all calls from www is suppose to go through the NodeJS application which will handle authentication and proxy the calls to unprotected REST API:s behind the firewall.

In NodeJS I am using Passport and [passport-azure-ad-oauth2](https://github.com/auth0/passport-azure-ad-oauth2) strategy. I am using express to create a session. Let me know if you need to se this code.

To authenticate a call is made to `/auth/github`. This will trigger a redirect to a github login page. When the github authentication is done a call is made to `/auth/github/callback` which will trigger a redirect to the startpage of the website.

In Rest assured I found [this](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/blob/master/examples/rest-assured-itest-java/src/test/java/com/jayway/restassured/itest/java/OAuthITest.java) example for OAuth login. I have tried it like this:

```
@Test
public void oauthTest() {

    String accessToken = "My very secret access token";

    Response r1 = given().get("/auth/github/");

    Response r2 = given()
            .auth()
            .preemptive()
            .oauth2(accessToken)
            .when()
            .get("/auth/github/callback");

    Response r3 = given().get("/api/user");
}
```

When I check the response in `R2` it looks like I only get the response from the github authentication. No session cookie from the node application is received like i thought.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be very happy.